# Bokeh TimeSeries Tooltip Date Shows as:?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I've looked at pretty much every single other stackoverflow question about this, but I can't get my date to show up in the tooltip:

```
dfx = dfx[['FullDate','DLM','DGO']]
dfx['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfx['FullDate'])
dfx['FullDate'] = dfx['FullDate'].astype(str)

p = TimeSeries(dfx, x='Date', tools='hover',plot_width=900, plot_height=350, xlabel='Date'
               ,ylabel='Cumulative Returns',source=ColumnDataSource(dfx))

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [("Date", "@FullDate"),("Value", "$y{1.111}")]

show(p)
```

Produces this:

[image]

I can show all the variations of this code I've done, but they all produce the same result.

My `dfx['FullDate']` column are all strings. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Bokeh are you working with? Also have you checked to see what is happening in the browser console? JavaScript errors are usually logged there. My guess is that your strings might be encoded in such a way that Bokeh may not know how to handle them.

Comment: Using `bokeh==0.12.5`, I'm not entirely sure how to check my browser console, but I will say that the label somehow works when I am not plotting datetime objects on the x-axis, but the strings instead. In that case, `hover.tooltips = [("Date", "$x"),("Return", "$y{1.111}")]` gets me what I want, but it bunches up the date strings on the x-axis, so not a real solution. When I use the above with datetime x-axis, I get what I assume is the epoch time, also not useful (although slightly better than `???`)

Comment: You should update to the newest version of bokeh (12.6) `conda install -c bokeh bokeh` I think that they might have fixed that bug.

Answer (score 1):

First up try to install the newest  version of Bokeh and see if that happens to solve the problem.

`conda install -c bokeh bokeh`

Try formatting your Datatime objects as strings with [Bokehs's HoverTool formatters](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields);

```
dfx = dfx[['FullDate','DLM','DGO']]
dfx['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfx['FullDate'])

p = TimeSeries(dfx, x='Date', tools='hover',plot_width=900, plot_height=350, xlabel='Date'
               ,ylabel='Cumulative Returns',source=ColumnDataSource(dfx))

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [("Date", "@Date{'%F'}"),("Value", "$y{1.111}")]
hover.formatters = { "Date": "datetime"}

show(p)
```

Comment: Tried it, but for some reason it didn't work. `FullDate` contains strings in this format: `"2017-08-07"`, you'd think that's pretty standard for bokeh to pick up...

Comment: Since you updated Bokeh have you cleared your browsers cache and reloaded the page?

Comment: Just updated and restarted jupyter/cleared cache...oddly still the same issue. I've also tried `hover.tooltips = [("Date", "@Date"),("Value", "$y{1.111}")]` but that also gets me `???`, only when I do `hover.tooltips = [("Date", "$x"),("Value", "$y{1.111}")]` am I able to see something. Have I set my source incorrectly? It seems to be able to pick up the axis values for the tooltip, but not the source dataframe values

Comment: Odd, still not working. I'm probably going to give up on this, makes no sense to me why it wouldn't be working.